# drupal Advertisement view sorted by Nodequeue relationship

Tags: drupal, sorting, ads

I have a Advertisement type of View listing Ads by taxonomy but I need to order them by Nodequeue and I don't see it available in the Relationships area. Is there a hack for this anywhere?
Drupal stack exchange won't let me add the much needed tags for this question. So I'm posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the view to have a relation from Advertisement to Node (Ad: Aid). Do this by going to Relationships and adding a relationship based upon "Ad: Aid". You'll then see under Fields all of the Node fields such as Title and Body available. Then add another relationship "(Node) Nodequeue: Queue".